# Hide a dialog from DOJO

Tags: jsp, servlets, dialog, dojo

Sorry for my english.
In my program there is a client-server communication (JSP - Servlet). When the data is sent to the server, a dialog Dojo with the message "Please wait ..." appears. That works. But if the answer arrives, this dialog should be hidden.

I try it by dialogStats.hide();. This does not work. I do not get the answer hidden, but the dialogue. Probably there dialogStats can not be accessed.

Code:

```
<script>
require(["dojo/dom", 
     "dojo/on", 
     "dojo/request", 
     "dojo/dom-form", 
     "dojo/json", 
     "dojox/json/query", 
         "dijit/Dialog", 
     "dijit/form/Button",
     "dojo/domReady!"],
 function(dom, on, request, domForm, json, dialog, button){

  var form = dom.byId('aktForm');

  on(form, "submit", function(evt){

    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var dialogStats = new dijit.Dialog({
                        title: "Blah",
                    style: "width:500px;",
                    content: "<p />Please wait ..." +
                             "<p /><div style=\"align:center; display:block; margin:0px auto; width:100px\"> " +
                             "<img src=\"bilder/loading.gif\" border=\"0\"></div><p />" 
     });
    dialogStats.show();

    request.post("StatsServlet", {

         data: domForm.toObject("aktForm"),
         handleAs: "json"

    }).then(function(response){
        dialogStats.hide();

        var fehler = dojox.json.query("fehlermeldung", response);                       

        if(fehler == ""){
                       // everything is ok
        }
        else {
           // error             

        }

    });
   });
});
</script>
```

How can I solve this problem?
I thank you in advance.
edu

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint on dialogStats.hide() and step debug into it ? My first guess is that your post returns an error rather than a successful response.

Comment: Hi Philippe, yes, it was a error and not a successful response. I thank you very much. Edu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Philippe said, You are probably returning an error.
Add an error function to handle the error

```
 request.post("StatsServlet", {

         data: domForm.toObject("aktForm"),
         handleAs: "json"

    }).then(function(response){
        dialogStats.hide();

        var fehler = dojox.json.query("fehlermeldung", response);                       

        if(fehler == ""){
                       // everything is ok
        }
        else {
           // error             

        }

    }, function (error) {
        dialogStats.hide();

    });
```